# Making return-key on keyboard dismiss it. IT WON'T

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I dropped a UITextField into a view controller via Interface Builder called *txtNameField, added the UITextFieldDelegate to my view controller, and then set the field's delegate to self in the viewDidLoad of the view controller. I made a call to

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn");
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
```

}

but the return key does not dismiss the keyboard.
Any ideas?

Comment: Checkout outlets and all small small things. Things you have described it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link a method to your textField's `didEndOnExit` event and put `[textField resignFirstResponder];` in that method.